# Hello I am facing an issue regarding maven dependencies in springboot project. While I am changing the version of org.apache.poi dependency version

Tags: maven, dependencies

I am facing build failure in Java spring project when I am updating the poi version from org.apache.poi 3.17 to 4.1.1. the 4.1.1 jar is not downloading to the libraries and build is getting failed. And the error is Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce(enforcer).
Please help me to solve this.
Thank you.

I tried adding jar file from external still same issue.

Comment: Can you show how you tried to add the  3.17 to the project?

Comment: Not trying to add the 3.17 to project it is already there in the project need to update the version to 4.1.1